# How to pause onCreate until boot completed?

Tags: java, android, widget

I host widgets in my app and it seems, that if i start my app before booting of the device is completed, widgets cannot be created properly. Widgets then seem to be not loaded completely or not initialized/updated correctly. For instance: BatteryBotIndicator-Widget, which shows the battery status in percentage, shows a value of "XX" instead of some number like "70%". If i then restart my app and try to recreate the widget with:

```
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
```

it gives me null for appWidgetInfo (i fetch appWidgetId from SQLite database). And widget cannot be recreated.

It is kind of difficult to debug the real cause in this situation to find out what is exactly causing this (Starting Debugger at the right time). I assume the AppWidgetManager is not ready yet or something.

What i can say for sure: If i wait until i receive the broadcast-event BOOT_COMPLETED all widgets are created properly.

So how can i pause the execution of onCreate until booting is completed?

I can think of putting the thread to sleep in a while loop until the BroadcastReceiver (BOOT_COMPLETED) is setting a bool-variable in application-data to true. But i dont want to wait for this event always at starting of my app, as you can imagine ;)

Comment: Have you tried to run your app normally and only add widgets when BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is received? Pausing onCreat I don't think would be a good way to deal with your issue.

Comment: thank you. Adding widgets only if a boot happened before isnt really nice either ;) Because i might install the app, add a widget, restart app without reboot. Result = no widget there!

Answer (score 2):

> if i start my app before booting of the device is completed, widgets cannot be created properly.

please explain more what exactly do you mean when you say - "not properly" . this might be relevant to understand if you're widget really depends on something related to the boot.

> I can think of putting the thread to sleep in a while loop until the BroadcastReceiver (BOOT_COMPLETED) is setting a bool-variable in application-data to true

very bad idea.. also from performances and design reasons

instead, why not simply register to boot complete broadcast from the manifest, and when you recevice it - simply send the relevant broadcast to update your widget?  AppWidgetProvider is already extends BroadcastReceiver,  so you can simply add it intent filter for boot complete broadcast.

this is how to add intent filter to boot complete:

```
 <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
         ...
    </receiver>
```

and this is how to react to it from the widget provider implementation:

```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
        doTheUpdateHereExactlyLikeHowYouUpdateItFromAnywhereElse();
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context,intent);
    }
}
```

for more information - follow this tutorial :https://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/android-update-app-widget-with-listview-after-phone-reboot/

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the effects completely and thx for your answer. i edited my question to make it more clear. Lets assume i have the id of the widget, that needs to be updated, in the BOOT_COMPLETED-Broadcast. Can you explain a litle bit more how to update that one by id? Further: I dont understand "AppWidgetProvider is already extends BroadcastReceiver, so you can simply add it intent filter for boot complete broadcast."

Comment: @maltonic42: I've updated my answer.  you can watch also this tutorial: https://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/android-update-app-widget-with-listview-after-phone-reboot/

Comment: thank you, i`m going to work with this and see where i`ll get. "doTheUpdateHereExactlyLikeHowYouUpdateItFromAnywhereElse()"....well i dont add widgets of my own to my app, but any widget provided by the system (let the user pick from all widgets available and add it to my app). So i dont update them myself. I only create/add them. They update themselve afaik. Maybe it is possible to force them to update themselve?

Comment: just added one widget on my homeScreen and rebooted. They behave like in my app and after boot is completed they are updated (which i am missing to do). So i guess your hint leads me toward the correct solution.

Comment: great. glad it helpd.. don't forget to acccept my answer :)

Comment: I will have to wait till tonight. Check it out then and if it works, i`ll accept ;)

Comment: Just started to try it out, but the thing is: I dont have my own AppWidgetProvider, since i dont have any own widgets and dont need to update them. I just use third party widgets in my app...how can i tell them to update after BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: @treesoft I`d never use backticks as apostrophes, so I`m safe to not create any unwanted code formatting in the middle of my sentences.